# Designig an ERP system

Tags: architecture, software-design, erp

I am providing a top level technical design of an ERP system. I have come up with an draft , but would need help to decide if I am on the right track.

I am taking baby steps, so I am concentrating on the HR module, as we all are familiar with it.

An HR module mainly has Payroll, Leave, Appraisal, Employee Welfare. All the HR modules run as batch processes in the night.

I would like to make the ERP cross - platform , so decided on python / C++ ( wxPython / wxWidgets come to my mind, or I may use normal Python /C++ )

I am not sure what shall the middleware be, if someone can help me with that that would be great. if you can provide me with advantages/ disadvantages of the middle ware that would be excellent, otherwise please mention the name of the middle ware, I shall look up the rest.

I possess skils in C, C++, and C#, so I am bit biased with C++, but your opinion counts .

```
   User Interface ( have not decided yet )
        |
        |
    Web Service ( my suggestion is Python.  )
        |
        |
   Business Logic ( my suggestion is C++ )
        | 
        |
   Middleware   ( need a message queue here, not sure what should it be, an open source middleware )
        |
        |
   Database Broker ( my suggestion is C++ )
        |
        |
   Data Base
```

Please feel free to provide your comments on the above design too.

**Example**

John is an employee of an organisation, which has 10,000 employees. John has a gross salary of 1000 USD.

Lets forget the ERP stuff for sometime and think a design for the following :-

1. HR enters Johns salary of 1000 in the UI
2. The data is passed to to the business layer via the Web service ( I think Python shall be a good choice)
3. The business layer is responsible for the deductions; not only for John but for the 10,000 employees who work in the organisation ( C++ is probably the language of choice ).
4. After deductions, the net salary is passed to the queue ( not sure of the middleware , please suggest)
5. The payroll process runs every month end, fetches data from the message queue and updates the database.

   Lets say while execution of the process , there is a power cut, so the process did not run completely, and the salary details for *some employees* were not updated. In this case the message queue should retain the unprocessed data, and before the next payroll process runs, the unprocessed data should be processed first.
6. The database stores the data. ( have not decided on the database yet )

Domain expertise is there , so I am looking for suggestion on betterment of the architectural design.

You are welcome to say "No, this is not the correct approach , you should do like XYZ". with a why is your approach better. This shall help me in comparing between your approach and mine.

Comment: Do you have any special requirements that rules out Java or .NET? They are often more productive than C++ for business software scenarios and there are a lot of different frameworks and libraries that can be used.

Comment: Anders - I want to make the software cross platform ,  so I ruled out .NET , though I know that if one installs MONO on *nix machines .NET code should run. C++ has probably been the language of choice of business logics in products. Java is not ruled out, just that I am not a Java guy ... please mention the frameworks / libraries you know of.. Whaterp, Intars. are some of the names I have come across.

Comment: Sweet mother of god, designing an entire ERP system from the ground up?  It sounds like the mother of all projects.  Are you sure you mean ERP, the technical design alone probably needs a team?

Comment: Jon ... :-) it needs a team, I am laying out the technical design.

Comment: I can't understand why you ruled out C#? Mono is really stable. Seems to me that you need to do more research.

Comment: I say go for it. It's going to be a ton of work, and you're going to need a big team of people, but go for it anyways. Try to make a case study out of it by enforcing design principles, and doing test driven development. If all else fails, you'll still have research. Sometimes you just have to start something.

Comment: This belongs in Programmers.SE

Comment: It may be worthwhile to look at making the whole ERP system web-based (with off-hour sleeper programs handling number crunching). Other ERP systems have gone this route (JD Edwards, etc). Solves the cross-platform necessity (at least for the end-users), reduces development effort considerably due to the vast amount of web frameworks available. Just a thought from someone else who is also designing an ERP from the ground up ;)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with JonAlb, it does sound like a mother of all projects. Have you considered open source implementations out there?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ERP_software_packages

Many of them use Python and one is using C++ (I was surprised to find even one :)

ERP systems is one of the most complex concepts (with a sizable degree of failure) in the enterprise. Just look at the definition:

> Enterprise resource planning (ERP) systems integrate internal and
>   external management information across an entire organization,
>   embracing finance/accounting, manufacturing, sales and service,
>   customer relationship management, etc. ERP systems automate this
>   activity with an integrated software application. Its' purpose is to
>   facilitate the flow of information between all business functions
>   inside the boundaries of the organization and manage the connections
>   to outside stakeholders

Please make yourself a favor and don't start from the ground up.

PS: if your company is building ERP to compete head-to-head with Oracle, Microsoft, PeopleSoft, SalesForce, etc., then you have to do what you have to do. I wouldn't be concerned about technology stack at the moment. Learn what ERP is trying to address from the business point of view first.

Comment: A more thoughtful way of saying what I was thinking...

Comment: Also.... I understand what your trying to do with the layers, but with such a complex system lots of multiple layers might make it even more complicated.  You should aim to short circuit (as Yuriy says) and simplify where possible.  Over engineering the design will make it even harder to implement.  Simple design and your more likely to succeed.

Comment: Yujir , Jon, the company is into ERP and they have strong expertise in that. They need a technical architecture ( top level ) for the design and that what I am doing.

Comment: The only thing I can recommend then is to study open source ERP projects.

Comment: Yuri .. I am also looking for open source ERP projects / frameworks, and I have mentioned them in them in my initial post. Besides, it would be great if you can let me know your comments on the software design.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to find out which response times are required and which amount of data will be processed. Then you have to find out, what skills exist in your team.
To use C++ its good, when you expect performance issues, but programming C++ is more expensive (needs more time, has more bugs) than Java. Except you have the C++ gurus and and Java skills.

Me personally: I made my last application (electronic health record) with Spring (Spring Security, Spring Web Services, DI, etc), Hibernate as a Database abstraction and ZK (www.zkoss.org) as a user interface technology (which is really wonderful, no worries about Javascript...). This is more easy to program than a C++/Python stack. For my team :-)

So why don't you switch to Java, there are tons of open source, Message Queues, everything you need...

Comment: Marc, thanks for your ideas. I shall keep them in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, looking into UML based modeling with use cases to capture the business case of architecture.
Reverse engineer and incorporate many  aspects of Adempiere and Openbravo.
You need Jboss, spring and good understanding of the management accounting systems.
You need to know Oracle, Postgress etc.